# Proof method terminology

Tags: logic, terminology

Suppose I have a statement $P \Leftrightarrow Q$. I prove that $\neg P \Leftrightarrow \neg Q$ instead. Is there a standard name for this method?

Comment: "Proving the contrapositive"

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I usually associate that term with implication, not equivalence. Is this an acceptable usage?

Comment: I see your point, but an equivalence is just two implications.

Answer (score 2):

$ P \iff  Q$ can be expressed as $( P \implies  Q) \wedge ( Q \implies  P)$.

Take $P \implies Q$, the contrapositive is $\neg Q \implies \neg P$.

Take $Q \implies P$, the contrapositive is $\neg P \implies \neg Q$.

so,

$( \neg Q \implies \neg P) \wedge ( \neg P \implies \neg Q)$

which is the same as

$\neg Q \iff \neg P$.

Answer (score 0):

Proving the contrapositive proposition